# if statement not working in sockets program, android

Tags: android, sockets, if-statement

I have a client server program using sockets,  one android tablet is server and the other android is client.  it works fine in the first example shown below where i am sending a simple message, but in the second example below i tried to use an if statement and it does not work. I wonder why this is?

receivedCommand is the textView

here is the first example that works with no problems

```
public String line = null;
try {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        receivedCommand.setText(line);
      }
    });
  }
```

now for the second example that does not work when using the if statement

```
public String line = null;
try {

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //receivedCommand.setText(line);

        if(line.equals("test")){
          receivedCommand.setText("test received"); 
        }

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try `line.trim().equals("test"))`

Comment: *it does not work* mean you are getting error ,code not executing,application crashing,....?

Comment: application not crashing, just not getting the if statement to respond, does not output the result

Comment: A--C,  yes. when using trim() it works perfectly. message sends with no problems.    put this as the answer and i will click the green check mark for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems all you had to do was

```
line.trim().equals("test"))
```

Always `trim()` when getting a String from other sources, it might just have whitespace where you don't expect it and cause the comparison to return false.